# If statement not working correctly in Objective C

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, if-statement, get

I am creating an application that requires users to enter a username and password. once they fill out the textfields the data gets sent to locahost using GET. My php is set to return the value 1 if the username and password match and 2 if they don't. But if i try to create a if statement like this:`if ([received isEqualTo:@"1"]) {
        NSLog(@"Access Granted");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Access Denied");
    }`

It returns as access denied even though if i do a Nslog it returns as 1 but it still doesnt say access granted.

This is AppDelage.m:

```
 //
//  AppDelegate.m
//  possys
//
//  Created by  on 11/11/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 . All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize username;
@synthesize password;
@synthesize super;
@synthesize alert;
@synthesize connection = _connection;
@synthesize receivedData = _receivedData;

       - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    - (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
        NSString *user = [username stringValue];
        NSString *pass = [password stringValue];
        NSString *strurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/index.php?username=%@&password=%@",user,pass];
        [self.connection cancel];

        //initialize new mutable data
        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        self.receivedData = data;


        //initialize url that is going to be fetched.
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strurl];

        //initialize a request from url
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        //initialize a connection from request
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        self.connection = connection;


        //start the connection
        [connection start];


    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
            [self.receivedData appendData:data];

        }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

            NSLog(@"%@" , error);
        }
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

        //initialize convert the received data to string with UTF8 encoding
        NSMutableString *received = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@" , received);

        if ([received isEqualTo:@"1"]) {
            NSLog(@"YUPYUPYUP");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"YNO");
        }
    }
```

This is my php:

```
<?php 

   mysql_connect("localhost","root","abc123") or die (mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("authentication") or die (mysql_error()); 

    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];


$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);


$sql = "select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());


$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {
echo "1";
}

else{
    echo "2";

}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe the value in the database is stored as a string, and so you will fetch @"'1'" instead of @"1"?

Comment: If you `NSLog(@"[%@]" , received);` does that reveal any white space around the result?

Comment: stripslashes wont protect from sql injection. `http://example.com/?username=x&password=x' or 1=1;--`

Comment: Do `if ([received isEqualTo:@"1"]) { NSLog(@"Access Granted"); }else{ NSLog(@"Access Denied -- received = >>%@<<", received); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceeding on the assumption that there's some sort of white space issue, you might try:

```
if([received intValue] == 1)
    NSLog(@"YUPYUPYUP");
else
    NSLog(@"NO");
```

So that has the system parse the text to obtain a number and then compares the number, rather than looking for an exact string match.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the isEqualToString: method rather than isEqualTo:

```
    if ([received isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        NSLog(@"YUPYUPYUP");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"YNO");
    }
```